# Prevent from solr query injections, when using solrj

Tags: solr, solrj, code-injection

Query to HttpSolrServer.

```
SolrQuery solrQuery = new SolrQuery();
solrQuery.setQuery(q);
QueryResponse queryResponse = solrServer.query(solrQuery);
```

I need to build a solr query, something like
"author:*user_inputed_text* title:*user_inputed_text*"
I need something like PreparedStatement, but I couldn't find something like that in solrj library. How to construct query that would not containt injection? How to make the string inputed by user - \user_input_text\ safe?

I am constructing query using concatenation. When I have, for example this code:

```
public String buildQuery(String userInputedText) {
    String query = "author:*" + userInputedText + "* OR title:*" + userInputedText + "*";
}
```

Then user can inject some subquery and receive the results, that is not restricted.
For example inputed string was: " OR title:". So, the whole query will be:
author:* OR title:* OR title:* OR title:*

In this case user receives all the results (they are not limited) and passes the pattern author:*?* OR title:*?*.

Comment: whats the problem...Explain problem you are facing

Comment: Actually it is not clear to me what you mean saying that you need to make it safe. Could you please post an example of how to make "unsafe" a query on Solr? Your're performing a query, so it is not possible to damage your indeces. I think you should give more details about your goal.

Answer (score 9):

Please consider use of a built-in solrj [`ClientUtils`](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_8_1/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/util/ClientUtils.html) utility class. By means of which you can escape `userInputText`

```
String escapedUserInputText = ClientUtils.escapeQueryChars(userInputText)
```

For more details take a look at the [queryparser syntax](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_8_1/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html?is-external=true#Overview) page.